# Copy whitelist of attributes from class one instance to the other

Tags: java

I'd like to know if it's possible to copy a list of attributes from one instance to the other. Ideally I'd like this to be done in a typesafe way, without using attributes as strings but rather being able to generate accessor handles at build time.

For example, usage should look like:

```
MyJavaBean sourceBean = new MyJavaBean();
sourceBean.setX("x val");
sourceBean.setY("y val");

MyJavaBean targetBean = new MyJavaBean();

copyAttributes(sourceBean,targetBean,Arrays.asList(MyJavaBean._field_x));
```

And only `sourceBean.x` would be copied to `targetBean.x`

My Java is a bit rusty, I'm sure I've already seen that somewhere. I've looked at bit at Lombok but it does not seem to permit this.

Does anyone have any hint on how to achieve that?

I must say that my app will have to maintain at least 50 whitelists of this kind, for a complex migration operation, so manually building 
copy methods or putting thousands of annotations on fields would be a pain, and type safety is important for me.

I'm NOT looking for:
- How to copy ALL properties from one object to another
- How to do a deep clone using Serializable

Comment: if it is possible for your class to implement `Serializeable` then serialise to bytestream and then deserialise it to new object

Comment: If I understand your requirements around type-safety correctly then not really, at least not short of adding a dedicated method to your `MyJavaBean` class, if that's feasible.

Comment: @diginoise not sure how it answers my question. I'm not looking for a deep clone of my object but to filter/whitelist the content that should be copied

Comment: Maybe a combination of [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/apimappings.html) for the mapping and [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/FieldNameConstants) for the accessor handles (the experimental `FieldNameConstants` don't look too bad IMHO).

Comment: @SebastienLorber fair point! I have misread it as carbon copy of all attributes. Serialisation is too big a hammer here.

Comment: @Marvin FieldNameConstants looks great, but Dozer seems overkill. Maybe I'll try FieldNameConstants with something like BeanUtils from some helper package...

Comment: Yes, unless you need the power of Dozer it is probably overkill.

Comment: how complex are the object trees? i.e. is the top level only primitive values, Strings, and arrays of these, or are these deep structures with many layers of objects embedding objects? If very shallow and primitive, JSON could be a used as intermediary and in the Map<String,Object> form, you could remove the unwanted properties relatively easy.

Comment: @diginoise as far as I know, a shallow copy is enough for my usecase

Comment: I'd use [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/). It's a code generation tool that generates code for copying data from one class to another. Seems like your exact use case. And it's simpler and faster than Dozer

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd that looks great and simple but not sure it's suited for my usecase. I need to copy from/to same class, not model to DTO. Also, the list of attributes to copy depends on the context and I'll have to handle like 50 distinct lists of attributes to copy (50 whitelists)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`Introspector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html) / BeanInfo API:

```
public static <T> void copyAttributes(T source, T target, Set<String> whiteList) {
    try {
        Arrays.stream(
            Introspector.getBeanInfo(source.getClass(), Object.class).getPropertyDescriptors())
              .filter(d -> whiteList.contains(d.getName()))
              .filter(d -> d.getReadMethod() != null)
              .filter(d -> d.getWriteMethod() != null)
              .forEach(d -> copyProperty(source, target, d));
    } catch (IntrospectionException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}

private static <T> void copyProperty(final T source, final T target, final PropertyDescriptor d) {
    try {
        Object value = d.getReadMethod().invoke(source);
        d.getWriteMethod().invoke(target, value);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that you could use some library like [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/).

But in this specific case could you not just use plain Java libraries and create a method like this one:

```
static <T> void copyAttributes(T source, T target, List<Field> fieldList) throws IllegalAccessException {
    for (Field f : fieldList) {
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(target, f.get(source));
    }
}
```

Here is a running toy example which you can execute:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

class JavaBean {

    private String X;

    public String getX() {
        return X;
    }

    public void setX(String x) {
        X = x;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" +
                "X='" + X + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

public class MyJavaBeanTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        JavaBean a = new JavaBean();
        a.setX("x");
        JavaBean b = new JavaBean();
        copyAttributes(a, b, Arrays.asList(a.getClass().getDeclaredField("X")));
        System.out.println(b);
    }

    static <T> void copyAttributes(T source, T target, List<Field> fieldList) throws IllegalAccessException {
        for (Field f : fieldList) {
            f.setAccessible(true);
            f.set(target, f.get(source));
        }
    }
}
```

What is the problem with this simplistic approach for this use case?

Comment: Hi, I'll definitively test that. Actually my project is quite complex, not coded by me, there is a bean with 3000 lines of code, sometimes with private/public methods, sometimes with setters... Not sure this simplistic approach would work in every case but will try it. Still not fan of using strings for `getDeclaredField `